# .Deb File Troubleshooting

Tags: 16.04, deb

Lately, I've been having trouble installing .Deb files. Whenever I try to install a .Deb file, the orange line that shows the installation process moves a little bit to the right, then the line disappears, the button no longer says Installing and reverts back to the install button, and then nothing happens. Any way to stop this from happening so I can install my files?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on what you explain I am understanding that you are using Software Center to install your `.deb` files.

I suggest you to use the terminal, this way you can see what is causing the problem and probably fix it directly in the terminal.

The majority of the times a `.deb` install and find errors, the system reverts the changes in order to avoid incomplete/dependency unsatisfied packages to be installed.

Please open a terminal (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Alt</kbd> <kbd>T</kbd>  in the majority of the cases) and enter the folder where the `.deb` resides. The place where you placed it when downloaded, via `cd foldername`.

Once you find your `.deb`, please run `sudo dpkg -i file.deb` (replace "`file.deb`" with the proper `.deb` filename and hit <kbd>RETURN</kbd>. After which you will be asked for your password.

Once you provide your password and hit <kbd>RETURN</kbd> the install process will start and show you what is happening and if an error occurs you will be presented with the error's reason.

You can then come back and edit your answer in order to include your terminal's output and receive further better support.

## But!

We must first try to see if the install process can continue by writing `sudo apt-get -f install`, press <kbd>RETURN</kbd> in the same terminal, provide your user password and hit <kbd>RETURN</kbd>.

This is going to attempt the fix of the unsatisfied dependencies and -if everything gets satisfied- the software is going to install.

If you receive further errors when running this last command, please add it in your question and we'll see where is the error and -probably- offer a solution for you.

Please let us know how you manage this issue and don't forget to include the details of the terminal's output and what you have done so far.

Good luck!

Comment: Thanks for the info! After following your instructions, it appears that to run the files I need I need to install python-apt. Terminal is now in the process of installing the needed repositories, and it appears to be running smoothly! Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

There are several ways you can install deb files: by using (Gnome) Software, Synaptic or gdebi. I personally prefer gdebi, it's the smallest app of its' kind and it has a graphical interface too.

You can install gdebi by opening a Terminal window and type: `sudo apt-get install gdebi`. Then right-click a deb file and choose 'Open with gdebi'.